# How to implement a loading dialog whilst dealing with $http request

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am currently writing an AngularJS webapp using parts of Angular-ui - notably UI-Bootstrap

I would like to be able to display a loading dialog while the app gets its data. On initial load I also intend not to show anything behind the dialog.

I have attempted the following and the dialog opens successfully, however it does not close when the data has loaded.

**JS:**

```
angular.module('MyApp', [ui.bootstrap])
.controller ('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $dialog) {
    $scope.initalized = false;
    $scope.opts = {dialogFade:false};

    $scope.data = [];

    var loadDialog = $dialog.dialog($scope.opts);

    $scope.loadData = function() {
        loadDialog.open('template.html').then(function() {
            // When the dialog is closed show the page content
            $scope.initialized = true;
        });

        $http.get('my/url').then(function(result) {
            $scope.data = result.data;
            $scope.removeDialog();
        });
    };

    $scope.removeDialog = function() {
        loadDialog.close();
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div ng-show="initialized" ng-init="loadData() ng-controller="AppCtrl">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

From reading various pages I believe that I am supposed to put the close function into a Dialog Controller, but then how will I call it?

Any other suggestions on how to implement this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks is advance!!

**EDIT**

To make it clearer, the issue I am having is that the function removeDialog() doesn't remove the dialog from the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updated Again

It looks like if you create a separate controller for the dialog and then load the data inside that controller you should be able to achieve the desired affect. The Plunker below shows how this could work,

http://plnkr.co/edit/T5z1hj?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function DialogDemoCtrl($scope, $dialog){

   // Inlined template for demo
   var t = '<div class="modal-header">'+
           '<h3>Loading</h3>'+
           '</div>';

   $scope.opts = {
     backdrop: true,
     keyboard: true,
     backdropClick: true,
     controller: "TestDialogController",
     template:  t, // OR: templateUrl: 'path/to/view.html'
   };

   $scope.initialized = false;

   $dialog.dialog($scope.opts).open()
      .then(function(result) {
          $scope.initialized = result.isInitialized;
          $scope.data = result.data;
      });
 }

 function TestDialogController($scope, $timeout, dialog){
    //simulate $http get
    $timeout(function() {
       var httpGetData = [1, 2, 3, 4];
       dialog.close({ isInitialized: true, data: httpGetData });
    }, 3000);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jonathan and I will probably use your method here, but the issue is that the function removeDialog() isn't working. I end up with the page loaded and displayed but the dialog is not removed from the screen.

Comment: Please check my update to the answer, I would suggest trying `$dialog.close();` in your removeDialog function. I believe I ran into the same problem initially when using the $dialog service.

Comment: Just tried that and I'm getting a console error: "$dialog.close() is not a function" ??

Comment: Just had a look at this and created this: http://plnkr.co/edit/xyrWqkxryyLuOsIOLAT5?p=preview I'm using $timeout to simulate the request delay but ti should to the job. The issue is the .then function on a dialog is only executed when the dialog is closed as far as I can tell. So we can't put the function to close it in there.

Comment: @Josh I think the solution at this point is to have the data load inside of a separate controller for the dialog and then pass the result and that data back to the DialogDemoController. See the updated post.

Comment: Thanks, that's all working! Now just to implement it in a more complex scenario...